# XMLHttpRequest with form data how upload works

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest

I am uploading files to to nodejs server on client side the code is

```
const uploadEvent = () => {

      setDisabled(true);

      if (file==="null" || file===undefined) {
        setText("Select a file");
        setDisabled(false);
      } else if(downloadCount==="" || downloadCount<1){
        setText("Enter a valid Download Count number");
        setDisabled(false);
      } else if(expDate==="" || Date.parse(expDate)<=Date.now()){
        setText("Enter a valid file expiry time");
        setDisabled(false);
      } else {

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("expiryTime",expDate);
        formData.append("noOfDownload",downloadCount);
        formData.append("isPublic",privacy);
        formData.append("password",passwordValue);
        formData.append("fileUpload", file);

        setText("File is being uploaded...");

        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.withCredentials = true;                        // XMLHttpRequest will include credentials like cookies in the request headers when sending the request to the server

        xhr.upload.onprogress = function (event) {
          // find the percentage of uploaded
          let percent = Math.round((event.loaded / event.total)*100);
          let loaded = Math.round( event.loaded/(1024*1024) );
          let total = Math.round( event.total/(1024*1024) );
          setText("Uploaded "+loaded+"MB out of "+total+"MB. Upload progress is: "+percent+" percent. Uploading...");
          // console.log(percent);
        };

        // handle error
        xhr.upload.onerror = function () {
          setText("Error uploading file:"+xhr.status);
          setDisabled(false);
        };

        // listen for response which will give the link
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            setText("File has been uploaded successfully! File id is: \""+xhr.responseText+"\"");
            setDisabled(false);
            setCopyText(xhr.responseText);
            setButtonVisible(true);
          }
        };

        xhr.open('POST',process.env.REACT_APP_UPLOAD);
        xhr.send(formData);
      }
    };
```

On server side (nodejs) the code:

```
const upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: 'file-sharing-files',
  }),
});


app.post('/upload',upload.single("fileUpload"),async (err,req,res,next)=>{
    console.log(err);
    const file = req.file;
    console.log(res);
    res.send("ok")

});
```

I am unable to figure out how the files are being send from client to server i.e. as buffer or stream or as a whole file.

I searched on google and found that xmlhttprequest send as a whole file. But if they send as whole file I can't see huge jump in ram usage (in system memory and in browser->memory->total heap memory).